# setting DOCTYPE using XmlService.Parse in google apps script

Tags: xml, parsing, google-apps-script

I am trying to use zillows API call to get their available data for a property. I used a random listing on their site for this example of my issue. I am having the error

"[Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: <SearchResults:searchresults [Namespace: http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd]/>]]"

when trying to progress past the XML string.

Google apps script code:

```
function zillow() {
  var zwsid = <zwsid>;
  var streetnum = "2023";
  var streetName = "SE 53rd";
  var streetType = "Ave";
  var city = "Hillsboro";
  var state = "OR";
  var full = streetnum + streetName + streetType;
  
  var parameters = zwsid+"&address="+streetnum+"+"+streetName+"+"+streetType+"&citystatezip="+city+"%2C+"+state;
  var url = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetSearchResults.htm?zws-id="+parameters;


  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var parse = XmlService.parse(result);
  var root = parse.getRootElement();

//set variables to data
  var test = root.getChild('response').getChild('results').getChild('result').getChild('street');
  Logger.log(parse)
}
```

here is the xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SearchResults:searchresults xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd http://www.zillowstatic.com/vstatic/80d5e73/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SearchResults="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd">
<request>
<address>2023 SE 53rd Ave</address>
<citystatezip>Hillsboro, OR</citystatezip>
</request>
<message>
<text>Request successfully processed</text>
<code>0</code>
</message>
<response>
<results>
<result>
<zpid>48595852</zpid>
<links>
<homedetails>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2023-SE-53rd-Ave-Hillsboro-OR-97123/48595852_zpid/</homedetails>
<graphsanddata>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2023-SE-53rd-Ave-Hillsboro-OR-97123/48595852_zpid/#charts-and-data</graphsanddata>
<mapthishome>http://www.zillow.com/homes/48595852_zpid/</mapthishome>
<comparables>http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/48595852_zpid/</comparables>
</links>
<address>
<street>2023 SE 53rd Ave</street>
<zipcode>97123</zipcode>
<city>Hillsboro</city>
<state>OR</state>
<latitude>45.504557</latitude>
<longitude>-122.928718</longitude>
</address><zestimate>
<amount currency="USD">395122</amount>
<last-updated>10/22/2020</last-updated>
<oneWeekChange deprecated="true"></oneWeekChange>
<valueChange duration="30" currency="USD">9444</valueChange>
<valuationRange><low currency="USD">375366</low>
<high currency="USD">414878</high>
</valuationRange>
<percentile>0</percentile>
</zestimate>
<localRealEstate>
<region name="Hillsboro" id="11914" type="city">
<zindexValue>341,800</zindexValue>
<links>
<overview>http://www.zillow.com/local-info/OR-Hillsboro/r_11914/</overview>
<forSaleByOwner>http://www.zillow.com/hillsboro-or/fsbo/</forSaleByOwner>
<forSale>http://www.zillow.com/hillsboro-or/</forSale>
</links>
</region>
</localRealEstate>
</result>
</results>
</response>
</SearchResults:searchresults>
<!-- H:003  T:56ms  S:869  R:Fri Oct 23 19:26:02 PDT 2020  B:5.0.66204-master.6d3b619~delivery_ready.62512d5f -->
```

I would like to be able to assign various children to variables to then assign those values to cells in sheets.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your expected values from `I would like to be able to assign various children to variables to then assign those values to cells in sheets.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result?

Comment: I would like to be able to extract the values, of say "zestimate", assign it to a variable, and then assign that to a cell value.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I would like to be able to extract the values, of say "zestimate", assign it to a variable, and then assign that to a cell value.`, unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: Any idea why I am getting ""[Document: No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: <SearchResults:searchresults [Namespace: http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd]/>]]" error when using XmlService.parse(result)?

Comment: Looks like you aren't being served well formatted XML. See [XML Document Type Definitions](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp).

Comment: I saw a method that converts the XML elements to arrays, would this be a better way to extract this information?